# decompression error when writing the file QtCore.pyd (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, installation, qgis-2.16

When I try to install QGIS there is an error :

> decompression error when writing the file QtCore.pyd  (or in German:
>   "dekomprimierung fehler beim schreiben der datei QtCore.pyd").

My C disc is almost full. But I would like to install it on some other disc and error is still showing up.

How do I solve this problem?